# Как послать сигнал о том, что окно было закрыто?

Tags: c++, qt

Я хочу, чтобы после того, как окно было закрыто, объект окна удалялся, а указатель приводился в nullptr.
Для удаления объекта после закрытия есть флаг Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose. Однако, чтобы установить в указатель значение nullptr, мне нужно, чтобы был послан некий сигнал, который я, на удивление, не смог найти.
Судя по всему, есть некий QWidget::closeEvent, но если честно, я совсем не знаю, как готовить эти ивенты.

Comment: Теперь нужно догадаться что за обьект, член класса или нет и т.д. и т.п...  Не получается вопрос оформлять с  кодом?

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите обрабатывать некоторое сообщение и своими руками обнулять все возможные указатели на окно? Ну перехватывайте вызов деструктора объекта окна - объект-то будет уничтожен, значит, деструктор автоматом вызовется.

Comment: Это не совсем ответ на ваш вопрос, но попробуйте хранить указатель на окно в `QPointer`. Он сам обнуляется когда объект уничтожен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

closeEvent - это не сигнал, а событие (event).  Подключиться к нему сложнее, и незачем (в рамках решаемой задачи).

Если хотите подключаться у событию "удаление объекта", подключайтесь к  [QObject::destroyed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed). Или можно вместо обычного указателя использовать QPointer<...> - он автоматически обнулится при удалении подконтрольнорго объекта.